# What IS the Lie algebra of a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, differential-topology, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces, unitary-matrices

In my differential topology class we have been working with Lie Groups, and we have learned that for example:

$$\mathfrak{u}(2)=T_{\text{Id}}U(2)$$

i.e. the lie algebra of $U(2)$ is the equivalent to the tangent space at the identity of the Lie Group. This is all fine to me, but when actually calculating this I found that the $\mathfrak{U}(2)$ is all skew hermitian matrices, and I just have no idea what this means. I mean the skew hermitian matrices aren't even a subset of $U(2)$ so I don't really know how to interpret this. If anyone could just tell me what I proved and what it means that would be fantastic.

Comment: The Lie algebra is a vector space, and no subset of the group. Skew-symmetric matrices form a vector space. The idea is to pass from Lie groups to something much easier, namely vector spaces - with a Lie bracket. Please have a look at, say, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467797/what-is-the-main-use-of-lie-brackets-in-the-lie-algebra-of-a-lie-group?rq=1).

Comment: The tangent space of a manifold $M$ at one of its points doesn't have to be (a generally isn't) a subset of $M$ in any natural way.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde what does Lie algebra tell us about the Lie group then?

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. (Almost) everything. There is a precise correspondence between simply connected lie groups and lie algebras. More informally, the lie algebra tells you everything you could want to know about the lie group near the identity, but it may miss some global topological features. For example, the lie algebras of the circle group and the real line are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment mentioned, tangent spaces don’t need to be able to be naturally identified with a subset of the manifold.
Think of a circle and a line tangent to it. The line isn’t a subset of the circle, but it still is its (affine) tangent space.

Comment: Ok yea I see that, but I don't get what the point is, or how to apply the poin of a Lie Algebra.